# mit scheme - can't move left when enter code

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

on linux, in shell I entered the mit-scheme, when enter code, I can't move left by "left arrow" key, why?

I searched on google, but didn't found a solution, any one help?

Comment: You might want to install **rlwrap** and start scheme with `rlwrap mit-scheme`.

Comment: @LePetitPrince It solved my input issue immediately, thank you so much!

Comment: @EricWang you can use `edwin` or `geiser`. With both you can have a text buffer and have an underlying REPL which IMO is much better.

Comment: @Rptx Thx, geiser seems need emacs, I prefer to vi, so currently I will stay with rlwrap now...